# Создайте программу и опишите в ней не менее 12 переменных, относящихся к различным скалярным типам данных

Tags: pascal

Создайте программу и опишите в ней не менее 12 переменных, относящихся к
различным скалярным типам данных.
С помощью оператора присваивания присвойте этим переменным следующие значения:

```
V;  254*V;  1-254*V;  -1*V;  65536;  3.5*V;  3.5E-45/V;  3.5E100;  3.5*V; 2^13; ’G’;  TRUE
```

где `V` – номер варианта (переменная типа byte)

---

```
Program Hello; 
var 
  V: byte; 
  a: shortint; 
  b: byte; 
  c: word; 
  d: integer; 
  e: 
  f: real; 
  g: 
begin 
  // readln(V); 
  // V:= 4; 
  readln(a); 
  a:= V; 
  readln(b); 
  b:=254*V; 
  readln(c); 
  c:=1-254*V; 
  readln(d); 
  d:=65536; 
  readln(f); 
  f:=3.5*V; 
end.
```

Подобие программы которую я начал писать

Comment: начал делать, но встретился с множеством проблем которые не понимаю. Ошибка на ошибке, не понимаю уже что делать

Comment: Ну Вы хоть покажите, что получилось то, пускай и с ошибками.

Comment: Я не знаю как именно на Паскале это делается, но вы делаете операции с разными типами, тоесть вы тип Byte пытаетесь умножить на число с плавающей точкой. В Паскале должны быть функции по конвертации типов, что то типа BytetoReal(V), и операция должна быть что то на подобии f:=3.5*BytetoReal(V);

Comment: Вы хотя бы сделайте, чтобы Ваш код компилировался.

Comment: А зачем постоянно readln? Достаточно ведь readln (V); и потом уже присваивать переменным значения, например a:=254*М;b:=1-254*V...
Ведь задание дано для того, чтобы вы понимали в каких типах переменных какие данные хранить.

Comment: Не совсем в тему вопроса, но это учебное задание явно не способствует привитию навыков "чистого кода". 12 переменных - явный перебор для метода, здесь нужен рефакторинг :)

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример 12 типов (Real в TurboPascal шестибайтовый, а в других может совпадать с другими типами) и некоторые присваивания. Нужно в хелпе посмотреть описания типов, их диапазоны, и подумать, куда, например, можно безопасно записать 65536

```
var
  V: byte;

  si8: ShortInt;
  ui8: Byte;
  si16: SmallInt;
  ui16: Word;
  si32: LongInt;
  ui32: Cardinal;

  sng4: Single;
  dbl8: Double;
  re6: Real; {Real48 в Delphi}
  ext10: Extended;

  ch: Char;

  boo: Boolean;

begin
  readln(V);

  ui8 := V;

  ui32 := 254*V;

  si32 := 1-254*V;

  si8 := -1 * V;  {Для номера варианта сойдёт, но не в общем случае. Почему?}

  sng4 := 3.5*V;

  dbl8 := 3.5E100; {но не single. Почему?}
```